# Connecting to same router over multiple ethernet ports

Tags: networking, debian, ethernet, interface

I have a Debian Stretch server with a network card.
I want it to connect to my (normal configured standart DHCP) Router.

So normaly i would say something like `iface eth0 inet dhcp`.
But i have a network Card installed with two additional ethernet ports.

The names of the ports are different based on the PCI Slot of the Network Card:

1. No Network Card installed.
   The Ethernet Jack is called `enp5s0`
2. Network Card is installed in PCI Slot 1:
   The Mainboard Jack is called `enp8s0`
   The First Card Jack is called `enp3s0`
   The Second Card Jack is called `enp4s0`
3. Network Card is Installed in PCI Slot 2:
   The Mainboard Jack is called `enp9s0`
   The First Card Jack is called `enp6s0`
   The Second Card Jack is called `enp7s0`

I want my Server to connect to the Router with `enp5s0`, `enp8s0` or `enp9s0` whatever is available as a normal dhcp client.

I don't want to use the other connections because i was to assign special Virtualisation Configuration later on :)

Can anyone recommend me a /etc/network/interfaces configuration which can achieve this ?

Comment: Why do you keep pulling the cards in and out and plugging the router cable into different card ethernet ports that it requires such a config?  Can you please explain what the purpose is... there may be a far better method.

Comment: The Mainboard itself has no grafical output. So when attaching a PCIe GPU i have to disconnect the network card. And i would like to have a solution which works in both cases.
The workaround is to reconfigure it every time when attaching the GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three years ago I had an issue under Ubuntu 12.04 where hardware was not being consistently named between two identical servers.  The fix was pretty simple and I think you'll be able to do the same type of thing under Debian.

My solution was to use udev to rename the device according to it's mac address.  This way, no matter what slot you plug it into, the device will always be named the same.

This should work under Debian.

e.g. get the mac address of the card with `ifconfig`

```
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:cf:30:2f:40:79  
          inet addr:192.168.0.114  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ecb9:ee41:b487:b54a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:338426 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:168905 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:385564822 (385.5 MB)  TX bytes:32387645 (32.3 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f9de0000-f9e00000
```

Then edit or create file /etc/udev/rules.d/010_netinterfaces.rules
(Under Ubuntu 12.04 it was called /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules)

Add one line for each card:

```
KERNEL=="eth*", SYSFS{address}=="20:cf:30:2f:40:79", NAME="eth0"
```

Then update your `/etc/network/interfaces` with the new names.

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Now you can plug your card in any slot and the device name will always be `eth0`.